# php trim line breaks

Tags: php, trim

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

The manual entry does say that I can remove any specified leading or trailing characters with trim. I am reading in an array with the file() function. Each element of the array read in has a trailing line break.

I used `trim($entry," \t\n\r")` in attempt to remove these line breaks, but nothing useful seems to be happening. When I `echo "[".trim($entry,' \t\n\r')."]\n";`, I see-

> ```
> [host2*2012-03-29 22:38:47 *129.118.243.193
> ]
> [host1*2012-03-29 22:48:16*129.118.243.194
> ]
> ```

What am I missing out?

Comment: Try `trim($entry, " \t\n\r");` double quotes are essential (something to do with interpretation of the escape character).

Comment: @Frits van Campen - I used the single quotes after I failed with double quotes. I have put the double quotes again, but there is no difference!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php#comment35408611_3446245

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
" \t\n\r"
```

not

```
' \t\n\r'
```

Note the double quotes

See the [relevant page of the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) for explanation of the difference between single and double quoted strings.

Also, take a look at the FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES option for the flags argument when using [file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Comment: I think 'FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES' is going to be most helpful, but I still want to know how to get rid of line breaks using trim()

Answer (score 1):

Just replace

```
trim($entry,' \t\n\r')
```

with

```
trim($entry," \t\n\r")
```

This is a string delimiter problem.
<s>But please not that if the line-break is on tow characters (like "\r\n") then it won't we totally deleted.</s>

Comment: I used the single quotes after I failed with double quotes. I have put the double quotes again, but there is no difference! I did not understand the 'tow characters' part of what you explained. If it is about the unix / windows CRLF or just LF, trim should have removed it, right?

Comment: You're right. My mistake. But if your bug is not solved, you should check what exactly is the last character of your string.  `$ord = ord($entry[strlen($entry)-1])` $ord must be 10 or 13.

Answer (score 0):

use double quote instead so that the characters will be interpreted properly.

Comment: I used the single quotes after I failed with double quotes. I have put the double quotes again, but there is no difference!

Comment: Does chop work for your? It may be enough if it works. Not sure why it would not work with trim though.